# Error setting NSNumber property of destination view controller in prepareForSegue

Tags: iphone, storyboard, automatic-ref-counting

I have a modal view controller that attempts to set an flag (an NSNumber property) of the source view controller that called it in its prepareForSegue method. It fails to build with the error "No known instance method for selector 'setGoToEditNewNote:'". Here is the code:

Source View Controller .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *goToEditNewNote;
```

Source View Controller .m:

```
@synthesize goToEditNewNote;
...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    // clear the flag
    goToEditNewNote = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:FALSE];
...

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if ([goToEditNewNote boolValue] == TRUE) {
        goToEditNewNote = FALSE;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"editNote" sender: self];
...
```

Modal View Controller .h:

Modal View Controller .m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"done"]) 
    {
        [self done];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setGoToEditNewNote:TRUE]; <<< get error here
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem may have to do with goToEditNewNote not being retained when the modal view is loaded, but i don't understand why not. I have set other properties such as the managedObjectContext in a similar way with success. Please be as specific as possible in your answer as I am a novice with ARC. Thanks - Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destinationViewController` is of the `id` type which doesn't contain a `goToEditNewNote` property. You probably want to cast `destinationViewController` to the `SourceViewController` type. This is usually a warning but it sounds like you're treating all warnings as errors (I do this too).

Your `-prepareForSegue:sender:` should look something like this.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"done"]) 
    {
        [self done];
        SourceViewController *sourceViewController = (SourceViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [sourceViewController setGoToEditNewNote:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
}
```

Comment: And also you set a BOOL Value to a NSNumber property, you should get a Compiler warning about this and not a Runtime error, but its possible that this coresponds with the Thing described by Mark

Comment: You're right. Passing a BOOL into an NSNumber is going to result in a segmentation fault. I've updated my code. OP, is there a reason you're not just using a `BOOL` to begin with?

Comment: @M and @D. I did as suggested and the error went away, however, the set did not make it back to the source view controller. I log the value right after it was set in the segue and that reported the goToEditNewNote = 1 as expected. I then logged the value in the viewWillAppear method of the source view controller. It reported goToEditNewNote = 0; Mark, originally I used a BOOL, but change to a NSNumber in an attempt to solve or understand more about the problem. Is this link relevant? http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=183427. Adding the setter didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: I gave up trying to use prepareForSegue to set the flag and implemented a delegate protocol. Problem solved. I thought I could use prepareForSegue to avoid the task of setting up the delegate protocol and have done this with other transition but it doesn't seem to work for the dismiss modal view controller transition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It took me 2 days and could't find any right answer on the web. Strangely, the same code in Stanford CS193p is working. Luckily I solved it now! The "set property method can not be found"  error's cause is forgetting to `#import "xxxx.h"`, where xxxx is the name of your segue's destination view controller. If you dodn't import, it never knows what xxxx's properties are!

Easy, now the segue works.

Comment: It has been a while since I posted this problem, but I think your are right. I have caught on to your suggestion since then. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: You are welcome if only we all help each other. It's very happy for me to have earned the first up here.

Answer (score 0):

At first if you are using ARC you NEVER have to use retain (or release, too). You only have to instantiate an Object, but you dont have to care about to delete it. But take care if Objects references in a circle at each other. If A references B, B references C, C references A and you access these Variables via a Variable D (wich points at A) and you no more use D the circle of A-B-C stays in Memory. Then you have to define one of the A-B-C References as 'weak'.

But to your real question: Is it possible that you missed the @synthesize Statement in the Implementation file?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the synthesize statement, which was already in my code, so there is something else wrong. I don't see a circular reference problem. If you see one can you point it out specifically please.

Comment: there is no circular reference Problem. Only want to use the chance to give a "Three-Sentence-Guide to ARC".

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you don't have any instance method that corresponds to the `"setGoToEditNewNote:"` selector; did you @synthesize your property (or write the accessors yourself)?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the synthesize statement, which was already in my code, so there is something else wrong.